# Fail to get kivy widgets by ids

Tags: python, kivy

I made this to code to show what I want but fail to do. I get the message: "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'" when I try to acces a widget.

Someone please explain how to use widget id:s so that you can acces them from anywhere using python code, i'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, SlideTransition
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random


Builder.load_string('''

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    SettingScreen:
        id: settings
        name: 'settings'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

    MainScreen:
        id: mainscreen
        name: 'mainscreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

    ThirdScreen:
        id: thirdscreen
        name: 'thirdscreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

<SettingScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        id: settingbox
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: getthis
            text: "this is the data"
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 1,0.1

        Button:
            text: "NEXT SCREEN"
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 1,0.1
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainscreen"                            
                app.root.transition.direction="left"                                

<MainScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: changethis
            text: "to be changed"

        Button:
            text: "Push this to make above into the text from TextInput on last screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.ids.changethis.text = app.root.ids.getthis.text #<<<<<
        Button:
            text: "Go to third Screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "thirdscreen"                            
                app.root.transition.direction="left"

<ThirdScreen>
    put_label_here: put_label_here
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            text: 'Make make label'
            on_release:
                self.parent.parent.makelabel()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: put_label_here
''')

class MainScreen(Screen):   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Screen.__init__(self, **kwargs)

class SettingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SettingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThirdScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def makelabel(self): #this should make a Label with text from TextInput on SettingScreen
        print('Runs function makelabel')
        thelabel=Label(text=self.parent.settings.settingbox.getthis.text)
        self.put_label_here.add_widget(thelabel)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager(transition=SlideTransition())
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='mainscreen'))
sm.add_widget(SettingScreen(name='settings'))
sm.add_widget(SettingScreen(name='thirdscreen'))

class testApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can fix this for you, but honestly I don't think you are making the right use of kv templates. But it will work anyway.

A new template is a rule by itself, it has its own root, so in return the application root (app.root) won't have direct access to children's ids defined inside their own templates. So you have to reach its direct child which makes a template containing the child you want to access then you reach that child by its id.

For instance, in your kv code, you will need to change line 63 (kv) from:

```
app.root.ids.changethis.text = app.root.ids.getthis.text
```

to:

```
app.root.ids.mainscreen.ids.changethis.text = app.root.ids.settings.ids.getthis.text
```

and line 99 (python) from:

```
thelabel=Label(text=self.parent.settings.settingbox.getthis.text)
```

to:

```
thelabel=Label(text=self.parent.ids.settings.ids.getthis.text)
```

Why shouldn't root (or any parent widget) access the ids defined inside separate templates ?
Templates, or Dynamic classes are made for re-usability, just like any none-static class.

Consider the following scenario:

```
BoxLayout:
    CustomWidget:
        id: wdg1
    CustomWidget:
        id: wdg2
    Button:
        text: 'change text of first label'
        on_press: root.ids.lbl.text = 'new text'

<CustomWidget@Widget>:
    Label:
        text: 'some text'
        id: lbl
```

Now The root widget have two instances of CustomWidget as children, thus two children Labels having the id 'lbl'. Which one should be called if the root called lbl directly?

To handle this, you can call lbl from its direct template instance. Thus: root.ids.wdg1.ids.lbl.text for the label inside the first widget, or root.ids.wdg2.ids.lbl.text for the label inside the second one.